# How to upload multiple folders containing images on the host in Android App Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, hosting

On the server there will be folders of the same name as Folder in the App, I send all the images in the folder under the app to the folder in the server. For example in the App with Foler A There are 10 images on the server also have a Folder A when clicking the button, it automatically sends all images under the App to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should get all files, and add multiple files,
Refer retrofit: [retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server)